# Present and Past tense together?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

" He threw the chair and table, grabbed Noah’s throat, shook him until his teeth chattered in his head, and, collected his entire rage in one heavy blow, **punching** him to the ground. "

Does "punching" make sense here (present tense) when "collected his entire rage in one heavy blow" is before it?

Comment: *He attacked Noah, arms flailing wildly*. No "present tense" there.

Comment: It's called the "present participle" but it has no actual tense. It gets its "tense" from the tense of the main verb.

Answer (score 2):

A verbform with *-ing*, like *punching*, is not "present tense" but a non-finite form—that is, a form with no "tense" (in any sense of that word) of its own.

If a non-finite form refers to a particular time, that time must be inferred from the context in which the form appears. For instance, in the sentence *The goons are punching Bill*, present reference is inferred from what is called a "present tense" form of *BE*, *are*; but the sentence may take past reference with what is called a "past tense" form of *BE*, *were* ("The goons were punching Bill"), or future reference with the modal verb *will* ("The goons will be punching Bill").

In your sentence, use of the non-finite form *punching* marks  the clause it heads (*punching him to the ground*) as subordinate to the 'matrix' clause which precedes it (*collected his entire rage in one heavy blow*); the *punching* clause is inferred have the same subject as the matrix clause and to occur simultaneous with the matrix clause or immediately after it.